# Assembly: without informing edi of the word size, why does my program jump ahead one number too far?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Take a look at this sample program from “programming from the ground up”. It cycles through a list of numbers and ends up putting the largest one in the status register:

```
.section .data
data_items: .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl data_items (,%edi,4), %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx
    start_loop:
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit
    incl %edi
    movl data_items (,%edi,4), %eax
    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jle start_loop
    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop
loop_exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

This is what the program is supposed to look like and I have no issues with it.

However, I’ve been experimenting a lot with removing parts of the program to see what they do more in depth. I have been experimenting with removing `(,%edi,4)` from the first part of the program, and when you do that by itself the program functions the same, and the largest number still gets left as the status code at the end of the program.

However, if you start the index further along the list (in this case the third number), I’ve noticed that getting rid of `(,%edi,4)` causes it to skip ahead one number in the `data_items` list. For example, running the program like this, it ignores `222` and says that the largest number in the program is `75`:

```
.section .data
data_items: .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $3, %edi
    movl data_items, %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx
start_loop:
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit
    incl %edi
    movl data_items (,%edi,4), %eax
    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jle start_loop
    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop
loop_exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

I know that you need to use  `(,%edi,4)`  to inform the processor of the word size in `data_items`, but what I wanted to know is why getting rid of `(,%edi,4)` causes our program to behave in this particular way.

Comment: For the next time: Use four spaces instead of `> ` bird tracks to format code as code.  You can mark the code and then press `{}` to have the editor do this for you.

Comment: You left `data_items (,%edi,4)` inside the loop, so you're still using a scaled index there.  You only changed the startup code to always load from `data_items` (no offset), instead of from the offset where your search loop starts.

Comment: Everything is just bytes, it's up to you to load the data you want from the right offsets.  Single-step your code in a debugger if you want to see how it works.  **There's no such thing as "informing the processor of the word size"**.  Perhaps you meant informing it that the elements are dword sized?  ("word size" is ambiguous for x86.  A "word" in Intel terminology is 16 bits, but the unit of atomicity for loads/stores is 64 bits.  Which happens to be the integer register size in 64-bit mode, but it was 32-bit Pentium that gave us 64-bit atomic ops.

Comment: But regardless of all that, the CPU doesn't know or care that your data is an array, or has any kind of element size.  You could load 4 bytes that overlap 2 elements, if you wanted.  It's up to you to use instructions that make the CPU do what you want, not up to the CPU to "understand" what you're doing.